# When to use anonymous JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand when to use anonymous JavaScript functions.

State differences between the functions? Explain when you would use each.

```
var test1 = function(){
    $("<div />").html("test1").appendTo(body)
};

function test2() {
    $("<div />").html("test2").appendTo(body)
}
```

I think the answer is that one uses anonymous function and the other doesn't to replace an empty div element.  Does that seem right?

Comment: no, it creates a blank div node with `test1` content and appends it to the `body`'s end. PS: deleted my answer since I misread the code in the question

Comment: Just as a side note, **`append` is faster than `appendTo`**: *http://jsperf.com/html-vs-class*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example it really doesn't make a huge difference. The only difference is that functions declared using `function foo() { }` are accessible anywhere within the same scope *at any time*, while functions declared using `var foo = function () { }` are only accessible *after* the code that does the assignment has run.

```
foo(); // ok
function foo() { ... };

bar(); // error, bar is not a function
var bar = function () { ... };
bar(); // ok
```

You usually use anonymous functions in cases where you don't need a named function, or where you're constructing objects:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });  // anonymous callback function

function MyObject() {
    this.foo = function () { ... }  // object constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a function like the following (which is another type of anonymous function) when you do not want to pollute the global namespace:

```
(function() {
    var pollution = 'blablabla';

    function stinky() {
        // Some code
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check John Resig's [Secrets of JavaScript Libraries](http://ejohn.org/files/js-secrets.pdf), especially page 47 for JavaScript function. Quite lengthy, but you'll learn more about JavaScript